# Mongoose: find and aggregate together in db.collection()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, math, aggregate

I have a collection in mongodb, called `recipe`, where I have a document, called `comments`, which is an array, and in each recipe is saving the comments. Inside the `comments` array I have a `ratings`, which type is Number. So I want to calculate the average the `ratings`, but don't know, how can I use the `db.collection().aggregate` code to work in the recipe collection, in the comments document with the ratings variable.

Here is the `recipe` collection in mongodb:

[image]

```js
const { Double } = require('bson');
const { timeStamp } = require('console');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: 'This field is required.'
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: 'This field is required.'
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Array,
        required: 'This field is required.'
    },
    ingredients: {
        type: Array,
        required: 'This field is required.'
    },
    categoryByServing: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Reggeli', 'Ebéd', 'Vacsora', 'Desszert', 'Levesek', 'Egyéb'],
        required: 'This field is required.'
    },
    categoryByNationality: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Thai', 'Kínai', 'Indiai', 'Olasz', 'Angol', 'Magyar', 'Egyéb'],
        required: 'This field is required.'
    },
    image: {
        type: Array,
        required: 'This field is required.'
    },
    comments: [
        {
            username: String,
            comment: String,
            date: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            },
            rating: Number
        },{
            timestamps: true
        }
    ],
    count: {
        type: Number
    },
    likes: {
        type: Number
    },
    recipe_id: {
        type: String
    }

});

recipeSchema.index({ name: 'text', description: 'text' });
const Recipe = module.exports = mongoose.model('Recipe', recipeSchema);
```

Here is the code, where I implemented the rating avg calculation, which is inside the commenting post method:

```js
 /**
 * POST /comment-recipe
 * Comment Recipe
*/
module.exports.CommentRecipeOnPost = async(req, res) => {
    
    let recipeId = req.params.id

    const comment = new Comment({
      username: req.body.username,
      comment: req.body.comment,
      date: req.body.date,
      rating: req.body.rating
    });
    comment.save((err, result) => {
      if (err){
        console.log(err)
      }else {
        Recipe.findById(req.params.id, (err, post) =>{
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
          }else{
            post.comments.push(result);
            post.save();




            db.collection('recipes').aggregate([
              {
                $unwind: "$comments"
              },
              {
                $group: {
                  _id: null,
                  avgrating: {
                    $avg: "$rating"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]).toArray()
              .then(results => {
                  console.log({ rating: results[0].avgrating })
              })
              .catch(error => console.error(error))





            console.log('====comments=====')
            console.log(post.comments);
            res.redirect('/recipe/' + recipeId);
          }
        })
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

There is a simpler way pointed out by [chridam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122005/chridam) in the comments using only a `$project` which I didn't figure out at first [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MLkt-mv136T)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: 1,
      avgRating: {
        $avg: "$comments.rating"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

..or using `$addFields` which will give the average of ratings as a new field `avgRating` for each record [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j-juhTRyai3) . you can use a project step after if need to get only certain fields

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      avgRating: {
        $avg: "$comments.rating"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

1. You have done the `$unwind` step correctly and now you will get a record for each comment.

```js
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "comments": {
      "comment": "commment1-1",
      "rating": 4
    },
    "name": "recipe 1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "comments": {
      "comment": "comment1-2",
      "rating": 3
    },
    "name": "recipe 1"
  },
...
```

2. In the `$group` stage group by something unique like the `_id` or the `name` and the `$avg` should be of `$comments.rating` instead of `$rating`.

In the end the pipeline should look something like this. [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B2VsGsMMLP8)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$comments"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name", //group by something unique for that document containing comments
      avgRating: {
        $avg: "$comments.rating"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: There's a much simpler way which does not even need `$unwind`, just a single `$project` or `$addFields` pipeline stage; [`db.collection.aggregate([{$project:{_id:0,name:1,avgRating:{$avg:"$comments.rating"}}}])`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MLkt-mv136T)

Comment: Thank you, it's working! I wrote after the aggregate the following code: db.collection.aggragate([..]).toArray()
      .then(results => {
          console.log({ rating: results[0].avgRating })
    })
Can I ask, that how can I store this aggregatie into the mongodb? If a create for example: storeAvgResult = { Type: Number}, and after how can I save the results[0].avgRating into these documentation? I want to import this number to the homepage.

Comment: @kiszod you dont have to save it you can get it query time and send to frontend. for example this query https://mongoplayground.net/p/j-juhTRyai3

Comment: Thank you, in demo is working fine, I have some problem with my code, because if I modify the aggregate to addFields, in the database is not creating the avgRating field with the value of avg. In console, im gettin null for the result.

Comment: notice that aggreggate only reads data. so addfields only creates a virtual field not a permanent field in the collection. if you want to add a field try update.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/k_PkSYO2Nqw

Comment: @cmgchess awesome, working perfectly now with update. I'm modified with this: db.collection('recipes').findOneAndUpdate({_id: ObjectId(recipeId)}, [ADDFIELD..........]).
So now its updating the correct recipe. Thank you!

Comment: glad to hear it worked